# Invalid array length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I encounter a Range Error when trying to run my code,

```
//earlier in the file
var yesArray = ["dummy"];


var numyesVote;
numyesVote = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yesArray"));
//The error takes place here
numyesVote.length = numyesVote;
```

I'm unsure of how anything could be creating a negative, or massive number. Could it be becoming undefined? (my original declarations for the variables take place in if statements)

Comment: why are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Show how you store the "yesArray" item in localStorage - you may be doing it wrong ... is it something like `localStorage.setItem("yesArray", JSON.stringify(yesArray))`

Comment: ooh, I just saw what you are doing ... nevermind how you store it, you're clearly doing something wrong there

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I'm a little confused. My setting of it is localStorage.setItem("yesArray", JSON.stringify(yesArray));

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean to do the opposite?

```
numyesVote = numyesVote.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also follow the same approach.

`JSON.parse` only come in picture if you are storing the data in local storage as a `JSON string`.

```
var yesArray = ["abc","xyz"];

localStorage.setItem("yesArray", JSON.stringify(yesArray));

var getArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yesArray"));

console.log(getArray.length); // 2
```